# How do I split a string based on multiple delimiters including text within parentheses in Python3?

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string based on multiple delimiters:

- `,`
- `.`
- `/`
- `\`
- `|`
- `+`
- `&`
- `;`
- `AND` (case insensitive)

However, I also want to extract text within brackets of different types, `()`, `{}`, `[]`

This is an example string that I want to convert:

`"Hello (Bob), Tree+Leaf. {text} AND Bye"`

And I would want it to be split into an array like such:
`["Hello", "Bob", "Tree", "Leaf", "text", "Bye"]`

I understand how I can split the substrings based on commas, spaces, by using `re.split(',|.|/|\\|\||\+|\&|;|AND', input_string)`, but I am not sure how you can also extract the text out of the parantheses in the same iteration as doing the other delimiter splits.

Also I would like it so that all the substrings are trimmed, for example if I were to split on this string `"Hello, World"` I would want the output to be `["Hello", "World"]` and not `["Hello", " World"]`.

Comment: Why do you think it can't handle all these cases? What have you tried?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've tried using the `re` library but don't understand how it can be used to extract the parantheses out of the string while maintaining other delimiters splits.

Comment: Use `[t for t in re.split(r'\s*(?:\bAND\b|[,./\\|+&;]|\(([^()]*)\)|\[([^][]*)]|{([^{}]*)})\s*', input_string) if t]`, see [Python proof](https://tio.run/##TY6xCsIwFEX3fsXDwSZtqYObImJxcBAnt7woFlIN1CSkT7A0/faY0e0euOdy3Ugva9Yx6reznsCrTBv3oftAXpsn7GBxUn1vgTW25RVcvVLlWT26GiZSX5rhcDlCM6pF5pJADARBZz0QaJPW6sH1mpjPcSjYfoNtqmMbRFWvEEO53MqAjIkb47LgyAOKBFIkkGFKcZpTnHmy8wr@n3HQHZAEHuMP).

Comment: @RyszardCzech Thank you that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
[t for t in re.split(r'\s*(?:\bAND\b|[,./\\|+&;]|\(([^()]*)\)|\[([^][]*)]|{([^{}]*)})\s*', input_string) if t]
```

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AND                      'AND'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,./\\|+&;]              any character of: ',', '.', '/', '\\',
                             '|', '+', '&', ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^][]*                   any character except: ']', '[' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##TY6xCsIwFEX3fsXDwSZtqYObImJxcBAnt7woFlIN1CSkT7A0/faY0e0euOdy3Ugva9Yx6reznsCrTBv3oftAXpsn7GBxUn1vgTW25RVcvVLlWT26GiZSX5rhcDlCM6pF5pJADARBZz0QaJPW6sH1mpjPcSjYfoNtqmMbRFWvEEO53MqAjIkb47LgyAOKBFIkkGFKcZpTnHmy8wr@n3HQHZAEHuMP):

```py
import re
input_string = "Hello (Bob), Tree+Leaf. {text} AND Bye"
print( [t for t in re.split(r'\s*(?:\bAND\b|[,./\\|+&;]|\(([^()]*)\)|\[([^][]*)]|{([^{}]*)})\s*', input_string) if t] )
```

**Results**: `['Hello', 'Bob', 'Tree', 'Leaf', 'text', 'Bye']`

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation